# MySQL query issue with Flex, php

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm trying to pass a MySQL query with variables from flex to MySQL using php.

This is the Query in Flex. Everything appears to be correct.

```
mysqlQuery("INSERT INTO poc_note_test (first_name,last_name) VALUES ("+firstName+"," +lastName+")");
```

When the query is passed to my server via http to be processed by PHP it returns the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Test_Value )' at line 1
```

From what I can see it is trying to include the final ")" as part of the value. I for the life of me cannot see how to stop this from happening.

Here is the php that is being used to process the query where it errors out.

```
$sql = $_REQUEST['sql'];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$err = mysql_error();
$cols_count = mysql_num_fields($result) or error_log('Invalid query: ' .mysql_error());
```

Any help will be much appreciated

This is the function passing the query. Maybe the issue is here?

```
public function mysqlQuery(sql:String,fid:String):void {

var http:HTTPService = new HTTPService;
var parm:Object = new Object;
parm.sql = sql;
parm.private_key = private_key;
parm.fas_db = mysql_db; 
http.url = mysql_url+"?irand="+Math.random();

http.showBusyCursor = true;
http.request = sql;
http.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, mysqlResult);
http.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, mysqlFault);
http.method = "POST";

sqlToken = http.send(parm);
sqlToken.param = fid;
```

}

Comment: try to run your query directly in your mysql database. if it worked then there is not problem with the your sql query.

Comment: I've done that. Everything checks out. Somewhere the query is being manipulated and I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
mysqlQuery("INSERT INTO poc_note_test (first_name,last_name) VALUES ("+firstName+"," +lastName+")");
```

to

```
mysqlQuery("INSERT INTO poc_note_test (first_name,last_name) VALUES ('"+firstName+"','" +lastName+"')");
```

put `'` around values

For removing `\`

```
$result = mysql_query(stripslashes($sql));
```

Comment: Now I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'TestFirst\',\'TestLast' at line 1

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'TestFirst\',\'TestLast' at line 1

Comment: @titancs I thin kin your `php` `magic_quotes` are enabled and it causes to add `\` before `'`. Either disable `magic_quotes` OR use `stripslashes` to remove `\`.

Comment: turning off magic_quotes worked. Not sure why I didn't think of that before. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Changed into

```
mysqlQuery("INSERT INTO poc_note_test (first_name,last_name) VALUES ("+firstName+"," +lastName+")");
```

to

```
mysqlQuery("INSERT INTO poc_note_test (first_name,last_name) VALUES ('"+firstName+"','" +lastName+"')");
```

IN sql , the string character are quoted in single quotes/double quotes.